# alignas specifier vs __attribute__(aligned), c++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, alignment, clang

I'm currently in the process of developing an OS kernel in C++11, and I've come across a question, I cannot seem to find the answer to myself.

Currently I'm aligning my paging structures, using compiler specific attributes (eg. gcc's `__attribute__(aligned)`), however I'm wanting to use the C++11 alignas specifier instead, on Clang++ this is no issue, as it gladly accepts 4096 alignment as parameter to alignas, however G++ does not!

So first of all, what's the main difference between the `alignas specifier`, and the gcc `__attribute__(aligned)`, obviously both ensure alignment to a specific value, however the alignas specifier in gcc seems to have a limit of 128, while the attribute seems almost limitless, why is this?

Also why can't one pass a const integer to the alignas specifier?

Comment: What version of GCC? If you pick GCC 4.8 here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/1hxHGg$0, it works just fine.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: 4.8; see http://liveworkspace.org/code/1kRIjz$0, with error `warning: requested alignment 4096 is larger than 128 [-Wattributes]`

Comment: Oh it's in a type. That sounds like useful information to put in the question :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Didn't knew it'd make a difference. :)

Comment: I didn't know that either, but seeing our two snippets, it appears it does make a difference.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Atleast using GCC, clang doesn't seem to care.

Comment: even if clang++ accept 4096 as a parameter, does it really align it on 4096 boundary ?

Comment: It does, apperently (when static_asserting the align_of)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems from the GCC support status, alignment support is not fully supported in [gcc 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html), but it is for [gcc 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html). `alignas` is also listed as a newly supported feature from the 4.8 [release page](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html).

Also, from the [alignment support proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2341.pdf) (3.11):

> A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to alignof(std::max_align_t) (18.1).
>
> An extended alignment is represented by an alignment greater than 
>   alignof(std::max_align_t). It is implementation-defined whether any extended
>   alignments are supported and the contexts in which they are supported (7.1.6). A type 
>   having an extended alignment requirement is an over-aligned type.

And from the same document (7.1.6):

> if the constant expression evaluates to an extended alignment and the implementation 
>   does not support that alignment in the context of the declaration, the program is illformed

That might be part of the answer too. I don't have access to the full standard at the moment, someone should be able to confirm this.

As for the difference between `__attribute__(aligned)` and `alignas`, i don't think they are semantically different, but one is just a compiler extension while the other is fully defined by the standard.

To answer your last question, `alignas` is only defined for:

```
alignas ( constant-expression ) 
alignas ( type-id )
```

Comment: I get that one is in the standard and the other one is a compiler extension, but why not have the same limit, as the implementation apperently would be the same? - Also what would be the argument for not supporting constant integers in the standard, as argument to alignas?

Comment: Actually it seems to work with constant integers too for gcc-4.8. The current limit might just be an implementation issue for GCC. I doubt the implementation is the same for named specifiers and compiler extensions, even though the semantics is. It might just be a temporary limitation.

Comment: You're right, it seems like it does work (it's the `__attribute__((aligned(...))`, that doesn't accept an constant integer), I kinda hope it's temporary or atleast switchable on the compiler in the future.

Comment: You answer is also why they definitely have a different implementation for both :)

Comment: I checked the source code of gcc 4.8 briefly, this warning fires for all over-aligned types (over std::max_align_t). My guess is that this is definitely a temporary issue and will be implemented later, since it is not strictly defined by the standard. The warning might remain though, as the behavior is implementation specific.

Comment: Please create a bug in http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ with your report/analysis of the problem (+test case)

Comment: I am not sure this is a bug. The standard says it should work for any alignment less than std::max_align_t and it is undefined for alignment above that. As far as I know GCC is compliant with that.

Answer (score 0):

They are different in terms of where it can be positioned. **attribute**(aligned) can be put as return type of function but alignas cannot be. Semantically they are same.